# How to send payment to the customer from Stripe account using API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, strip

One of my client `Ruby on Rails` project have a functionality of get payment from customer in his `stripe account`.

Now, He needs to pay that payment to the item owner after deducted commission. So, how we can pay from s`tripe account to particular customer account` using `API` in Rails?

I have checked `many API's` but not clear which exactly use for it.

Any one have a idea or experience in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the Stripe guide on [Using Checkout with Rails](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails).

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive if a customer token can be used to send funds to, but if so or not, the following still applies.

If the customer has a connected account (or customer token), you can then use "transfer" to transfer the funds to them.